# registering jquery in asp.net Master page

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have asp.net web project with following folder structure

```
MyProject
  -FolderOne
     -PageOne.aspx
  -FolderTwo
     -PageTwo.aspx
  -HomePage.aspx
  -Site.Master
```

I registered `<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js"></script>` in Site.Master . My Problem is that , function using this jquery works in HomePage.aspx but not in PageOne.aspx and PageTwo.aspx .
But it's works when i register `<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js"></script>` in each PageOne.aspx and PageTwo.aspx . Is there any way if I want to register my script **only in Site.Master** ?

Comment: if you added master page properly in PageOne and PageTwo, then, it shouldn't happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry my earlier solution assumed that it was an MVC project.

You need to use ResolveUrl in Site.Master so that PageOne & PageTwo work properly

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='<%= ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js")%>'></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

PageOne and PageTwo must refer to the master page in order to get access to the includes in the master page. Otherwise they need their own local includes

Comment: I add this in PageOne `<%@ Page Title="PageOne" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeFile="PageOne.cs" Inherits="PageOne" %>` , is it enough ?

Comment: MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" is by default when we add page with master page

Comment: Of course it is sangram parmar  :) TGH said `must refer to the master page` . Is there a better way to do it ?